# How the offset should be configured for a new consumer group for an existing topic when source connectors can't be paused

Tags: apache-kafka

We have an existing topic where the data gets published by JDBC source connector using the mode increment + timestamp (The source connector uses increment+timestamp (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html#incremental-query-modes)

We have existing consumer groups which consumes data from some existing topics. Now we are introducing a new consumer group (call this group k) which should consume data from the same existing topics and should write to database. As a first step, we have an initial data migration workflow to take a dump of source database and copy the dump to destination database before starting consuming messages from existing topic.

Now when the consumer group starts, I am wondering what should be the offset it should start with?

One option is to use latest. But the problem is that existing source connectors would be publishing data to existing topics when initial data migration is being done for this new consumer group. In our case we have 10s of tables to be migrated and there could be a gap where the table dump was taken but still some changes are getting done to the source database and so data will get added to topics. So, there is a chance that we may miss to process some records.

We don't have the option to pause the source connectors which would solve the problem for us.

If we use offset earliest we will end up processing all the old data from kafka topic which is not required as we have done an initial data migration.

We want to maintain only one source connector regardless of the number of consumer groups.

I was going through kafka consumer APIs like seek which takes timestamp. I can note down the time before initial data migration and call consumer.seek once the consumer group has started and partitions are assigned. But I couldn't find any docs saying that the timestamp is GMT based or something else. Is it ok to use this API by passing the time which is number of milliseconds elapsed from epoch?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this sentence correctly: "If we use offset latest we might lose some data as source connectors might have written some data to the topic during initial data migration" the topic will end up having some data from initial loads and CDC data mixed up, so there is no offset that clearly distinct this. Therefore, you will not get far setting any particular offset.

I see the following options:

- Have your consumer group K filtering out initial load data and read from earliest
- Produce the initial load data to a dedicated topic
- If possible perform the initial load outside of business hours so that no CDC data is flowing (maybe over week-end or bank holidays)

Comment: "If we use offset latest we might lose some data as source connectors might have written some data to the topic during initial data migration" - the existing source connectors would be CDCing the data to existing topics. There is a separate workflow to do initial data migration, which doesn't write anything to existing topics. Once this workflow is done, the new consumer group has to read the data from the existing topics.

We want to maintain only one source connector regardless of the number of consumer groups.

Comment: The existing data migration is to migrate data from source database to destination database. Then we start the CDC.

Comment: Thanks mike for your patience and time in reading this.